# Get objects in array with duplicated values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get elements from an array of objects where one of that object's properties (`name` in this case) is duplicated--in other words, appears in some other object in the array.

data

```
var data = [
  {id:1, name:"sam", userid:"ACD"},
  {id:1, name:"ram", userid:"SDC"},
  {id:1, name:"sam", userid:"CSTR"}
];
```

i need to check all row and get all the array value where name property is duplicating.

the expected output:

```
[
  {id:1, name:"sam", userid:"ACD"},
  {id:1, name:"sam", userid:"CSTR"}
]
```

my code

```
Array.from(data).map(x => x.name)
```

but it is returning all the values.

The code should not create any performance issue because array will contain more than 500 rows.

Comment: Just curious, do you know what Angular is, and what the difference between Angular and JavaScript and TypeScript is?

Comment: Just curious. What did you think `Array.from(data)` was going to do, or why it was necessary/

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a framework, not a language. There is no *Angular* in your problem.

Let me understand if I understood well. You have an array of objects and you want to keep all the elements that are duplicate and get rid of others, all right? You can try:

```
data.reduce((acc, value, i, arr) => {
  if(acc.some(v => v.name === value.name)) return acc;
  let filtered = arr.filter(v => v.name === value.name);
  return filtered.length > 1 ? acc.concat(filtered) : acc;
}, []);
```

Or you can sort your array in first instance, in order to improve performance:

```
const sort = (a, b) => a.name.toUpperCase() < b.name.toUpperCase() ? -1 : 1;

let duplicates = [];

let sortedArray = data.sort(sort);

for(let i=0; i<sortedArray.length - 1; i++) {
  if(sortedArray[i].name === sortedArray[i+1].name) {
    duplicates.push(sortedArray[i], sortedArray[i+1]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the computational complexity of this is? How is it going to perform given the OP's comment about the input containing lost of items?

Comment: The complexity should be O(n^2), it would be ok for about 500 items.

Comment: Nice question anyways, I think we can decrease complexity using the "delete" keyword, but javascript doesn't love deleting array items so the user couldn't enjoy performance

Comment: Another solution could be sorting items by name and check if two adjacent items have the same name. The complexity would be O(n) + O(n log(n)) = O(n log(n))

Answer (score 0):

The brute force approach would be to filter the array to keep only those elements with duplicated names, as expressed by the filter function `duplicateName`.

```js
// Is there more than one element in an array satisfying some predicate?
const hasMultiple = (arr, pred) => arr.filter(pred).length > 1;

// Is this element a duplicate in the context of the array?
const duplicateName = (elt, idx, arr) => hasMultiple(arr, e => e.name === elt.name);

// Test data.
var data = [
  {id:1,name:"sam", userid:"ACD"},
  {id:1,name:"ram", userid:"SDC"},
  {id:1,name:"sam", userid:"CSTR"}
];
   
console.log(data.filter(duplicateName));
```

However, this is going to have poor performance (`O(n^2)`) in the case of many elements. To solve that problem, you're going to need to preprocess the array. We'll create an object with a property for each name, whose value is an array of all the elements in which that name occurs. This operation is usually called `groupBy`. Several popular libraries such as underscore will provide this for you. We'll write our own. After grouping, we will filter the object of groups to remove those with only one member.

```js
// Group an array by some predicate.
const groupBy = (arr, pred) => arr.reduce((ret, elt) => {
    const val = pred(elt);
    (ret[val] = ret[val] || []).push(elt);
    return ret;
  }, {});
  
// Filter an object, based on a boolean callback.
const filter = (obj, callback) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((res, key) => {
    if (callback(obj[key], key, obj)) res[key] = obj[key];
    return res;
  }, {});

// Remove groups with only one element.
const removeNonDups = groups => filter(groups, group => group.length > 1);

// Test data.
var data = [
  {id:1,name:"sam", userid:"ACD"},
  {id:1,name:"ram", userid:"SDC"},
  {id:1,name:"sam", userid:"CSTR"}
];

console.log(removeNonDups(groupBy(data, elt => elt.name)));
```

Comment: I thought a similar approach but I know that JavaScript has a performance leak with the "delete" keyword. Do you know if the computational complexity decrease balance the performance leak?

Comment: I have no idea what kind of performance leak you might be talking about. Please provide a reference.

Comment: Anyway, I've removed the use of `delete`.